# Lambda performance killer

Tags: c#, performance, linq, lambda

I am wondering why would C# provide the lambda expression if it is a performance killer?

Trying to run the following:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
 sw.Start();
 x = x.Select((int i) => i += 1).ToArray();
 sw.Stop();
 Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedTicks);
```

AND

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) y[j] += 1;
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedTicks);
```

for x = 1000, we would find huge difference.

**Is there an appropriate use case for lambda?**

Comment: Because you're doing it wrong.

Comment: They wouldn't. LINQ hasn't obsoleted `for` loops, thank god.

Comment: What are those two code snippets supposed to do? Tey don't make much sense without context. Also make sure you are not micro-optimizing your code. Most time, tje performance bottleneck will be elsewhere in your code (whem doing I/O).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we must remember LINQ is a language for QUERIES. of course, you can do other stuff with it, as well, such as updating a collection (a how to do asked very often on SO) or running a loop, but why would you do this? LINQ and lambda expressions are not a new, total replacment of procedural programming, its merely a tool which can be used when suitable.

As other query languages (such as t-sql), LINQ provides you the tools to define WHAT you want to get, and not HOW you want to get it, which also allows you to create a language - independant queries, that you can later parse to whatever you want. It may be very convinient and generic to use in many cases, and also can abstract the underlying data types/data sources, but it also means you leave the concrete implementation of HOW to get whay you asked for to whoever wrote the parser for your queries.

I suggest you read about some sample linq providers out there. Take a look at LINQ to LDAP for example: such providers allow you, as a develoepr, to concentrate only on the data you want, and not on the underlying data structure/Active Directory API, which can be pretty annoying to use.

As with every other tool you get, you need to ask yourself what you want to get, and if this tool is the best way to go. A good analogy would be using loops in sql servre query; Of course, it can be done, but you will usually prefer to build a select which will let the sql engine to decide HOW to execute your query.

Answer (score 8):

Your code making use of a lambda expression takes `x` and copies all 1000 of its elements into a new array, computing new values for all 1000 of their values. That's obviously going to be more expensive than just modifying the 1000 existing elements in the same array in-place.

> how to do it right !

Easy: use LINQ and delegates for the right purpose. Taking an array of numbers and incrementing all its values isn't something I would use LINQ for.

Just because C# provides lambdas (which are really syntactic sugar for delegates and expression trees), doesn't mean you have to use them for everything. If you use them for the right purposes, you'll notice that they don't incur any real performance hits, at least not as egregious as what you're observing.

Comment: but even if I consider doing only this, just for testing purposes,

    x.Select((int i) => i += 1); 

there will be a big difference as well comparing it to 

    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) y[j] += 1;

Comment: If you say it's "just for testing purposes", why does that matter? All it is is a contrived test.

Comment: Exactly.  It's like comparing the straight loop to assembly language.   C# is such a performance killer.

Comment: hmmm... I agree with you ,,, can you show me an example where lamda must or it is better to be used

Comment: The only real use of LINQ to Objects is to make the code look simpler. It's main goal is to make complex tasks easier to implement, not to make them faster. For example, consider you have a `HashSet` of values and you want to iterate them in a specific order. You could copy them to an array and sort that or you could simply use the `OrderBy()` extension method. Another example is counting items that satisfy a condition. You could either write `foreach(item in collection) if (item satisfies condition) num++;` or just do `num = collection.Count(item => condition);`.

Answer (score 0):

> why would C# provide the lambda expression if it is a performance killer?

Because performance usually is not that important compared to the importance of readable code.